# How do I add system library path to Jamfile which is already in the ld search path?

Tags: boost, g++, ld, boost-build

**bjam link failure:**

I have a project which fails to link due to being unable to find `libkrb5`.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkrb5
```

I am specifying the library in my `Jamfile` as follows:

```
lib krb5 ;
```

**Jamfile additional library search paths:**

The project in my Jamroot only has a single additional library path:

```
<library-path>/usr/local/lib
```

So only this path is added to the ld search path:

```
"g++" -L"/usr/local/lib"
```

**Library exists in standard location:**

However, locating the library shows it is stored under a standard multiarch path

```
$ locate libkrb
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so
```

The above location is in my **ld search path**:

```
$ ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
```

**Questions:**

- Why does bjam not find the library in the system search path?
- How can I tell boost.build where this library is?

Comment: Well, it's not bjam that isn't finding the library, it's g++. If `g++ -lkrb5 ...` can't find the lib, then simple `lib krb5 ;` in a jamfile won't be enough. Have you tried `<library-path>/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`?